# How would I graph this equation

Tags: summation, graphing-functions

Obviously I've forgotten things in the last 12 years because between my graphing calculator and wolfram alpha I can't figure out how to graph this correctly. Pretty sure its a summation but after a couple hours of looking at syntax online and wolfram alpha's documentation I haven't come up with the correct writing.

$x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{n-1} * 1.75$ where $ x_1 = 100 $, for n = 1 to n = 100

I know how to solve for any particular `n`  in fact I have a line of code in my current program that does it for me (working on a role playing game (rpg))

`exp_for_next_level += exp_for_next_level * exp_modifier_for_player_level`

But I want to be able to graph it so I can play with various modifiers and starting experience and see where that puts me quickly for balancing purposes.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Did you mean $x_n$ instead of $x$?  Did you notice that $x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}\times 1.75=2.75\times x_{n-1}$?

Comment: Huh???  $x_{n-1} + x_{n-1} * 1.75$??  Isn't that $2.75\ x_{n-1}$?

Comment: @lulu I did mean $x_n$

Comment: Ok...so $x_n=(2.75)^{n-1}\times 100$, right?

Comment: @lulu that does seem to be the case

Comment: It might help to edit the question to add the first three or four terms; if the recursion relation is not as currently typed, examples of terms should help debug the formula.